# PHP 5.5, how to enabled odbc_connect()?

Tags: php, pdo, odbc, redhat

I'm using PHP 5.5.6 on Redhat6.

When I run the following PHP scrip I get a `Call to undefined function odbc_connect()`error.

```
$u = 'smthg';
$p = 'smthgelse';

$conn = odbc_connect('MSSQL-PHP', $u, $p , SQL_CUR_USE_DRIVER) ;
```

I configured my odbc.ini file as following:

```
[MSSQL-PHP]
Driver                  = SQL Server Native Client 11.0
Server                  = 10.33.37.2
Database                = MyDBName
```

I also try to connect to my server with PDO but I also get a `Class 'PDO' not found` error.

I thought that both ODBC and PDO extension was already included in PHP5.5, and there was no extension to add into my php.ini file. But a `php -r 'phpinfo();' | grep odbc` or the same with pdo give me nothing.

What did I miss?

Comment: Have you enabled oracle extension(extension=php_oci8.dll  or  
extension=php_oci8_11g.dll) in php.ini file?

Comment: @KumarA As far as I understand odbc needs some oracle tools to work fine?

Comment: Check this url: http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/php/apache_odbc.html

Comment: @KumarA So I'm required to recompile my php to add a module? Can't I dynamically load it?